# Kotlin string escape special char: $

Tags: kotlin

This is my scratch:

```
// how to present $-$ as Kotlin string
val var1 = "\$-\$"
val var2 = "\$-$"

print("${var1.count()}: $var1")
print("${var2.count()}: $var2")

print("${var1 == var2}")
```

[image]
can someone explain why var2 works?  (no need to escape 2nd $ char?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template expression in a template String in Kotlin is a dollar (`$`) followed by either a name or an expression in curly braces (see the [String templates documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates)).

The single `$` sign which is followed by nothing in your String `var2` does not need to be escaped because it is not a template expression.